# What is the greek symbol that represents the ratio of the length and with in a rectangle.

Tags: quadratics, rectangles, ratio

I understand that there is pi, but I was provoked by a question that asked this, "I have a rectangle and if I cut a square off of it it produces the same type of rectangle. I know that the width is 1 meter but what is the length?" Please help me out and tell me the symbol and what it represents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the golden number/ratio and is represented by the Greek letter phi :$$\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$.

Comment: Some call it $\tau$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I didn't know. Where do people write it as tau?

Comment: One can search. It is mentioned in the Wikipedia article, but buried, and mentioned early in the [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html) article.

Comment: Again thank you so much! It helped me with my homework!